# How to disable a port using Rest API?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I would like to send a curl command to disable all xdbc ports. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to write a piece of code (tested with QueryConsole for instance), and POST that against https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval. Slightly safer would be to put that code in some database, and use `/v1/invoke` instead.

The elegant way would be to make multiple calls against the Manage REST api, to discover and update the necessary app-servers. See this section of the documentation:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management/app-servers

Note though that in both cases, ML REST api instances, implemented as HTTP app-servers, can also accept XDBC traffic, including the default running at 8000, unless explicitly told not to at creation time.

The main question here is though, why disable all XDBC servers? It is easy enough to not hand out xdbc execute privileges to non-admin users..

HTH!

Comment: Disabling is required before upgrade to be on the safer side.

Answer (score -3):

1. write a command file .
2. open a restful api to controle executing the file

by the way, most programming language suport exec system command straightly.

Comment: did i misunderstand something~